# Any ideas to mask the input?

Tags: java

I have been working on small project of mine which has the account name and account password as an array .

After the program runs it ask you to enter your username followed by password then it matches it with its database. If correct: proceed; if not: display login fail.

What I want is when the user enters the password instead of displaying the password as `1234` I want to show it as `****`.

```
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public int UserNameAndPassword(){
    System.out.println("Pleass Enter your username:");
    String user =in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Pleass Enter your Password:");
    String pin = in.nextLine();
   int p= FindNameAndPassword(user,pin);
return p;
}
```

main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HelpingMethodes h =new HelpingMethodes();       
    Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);     
    while(true)
    {
        int position,choise;
        position = h.UserNameAndPassword();
        boolean login = true;
         while(position==-1)
         {
            System.out.println("You entered wrong Username or Password");
            System.out.print("Pleas try again\n");
            position=h.UserNameAndPassword()        
        }
```

Is there any simple way to achieve that in Java?

Comment: what are you using to get the input? html? jsp? jsf? swing? thats kind of a crucial piece of information!

Comment: That's not even close to what hashing means. What UI platform are you using?

Comment: @M21B8 no just simple Scanner

Comment: Eclipse and Netbeans have nothing to do with your question, please don't re-add them. If they are ontopic, please specify how.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel for now I want to learn . The input will be through eclipse

Comment: You are looking for "masking" instead of "hashing".

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'mm gonna paste the code right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [Console.readPassword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29). Although it will not mask the password with *****, it does the job as it hides the text inputted. Quick code snapshot:

```
 char[] password = System.console().readPassword("Password: ");        
 System.out.println("Password is: "+ password);
```

**Note:** You must run the program via command line. If you're running this through an IDE, you will get **null** on the Console object.

You'll find a detailed tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/console_readpassword.htm).

If you prefer *not* to use Console, you'd have to implement an alternative solution. You'd have to write a thread that overwrites the input as it's received, which won't be a trivial task. As far as I know, Scanner does not have a built-in masking method.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code from the tutorial in your post? That way the quality of the answer isn't very relying on an external source and it saves future browsers an extra click.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword() instead of Scanner.

Also, this is called password masking, not hashing, just FYI.